# jQuery autocomplete on sequential call throws JS error on IE7 standalone

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, jquery-autocomplete

We have a textbox coupled with jQuery UI Autocomplete v1.8.14

It basically works great and without bugs except a certain scenario in IE7 standalone. Let's assume that a user is inputting a letter and the first AJAX request goes out for the autocompleter results. The response isn't yet back but the user inputs another letter. At this point the first request is being aborted be default and a second one is started to retrieve the new results for the new search string. This makes sense as is spares bandwidth and lost execution time but unfortunately it fails on IE7.

The following image is showing what happens using Firebug in Firefox. Essentially all browsers work correctly except IE7 (even IE6 and IE8).

[image: Attached image showing the behavior in Firebug]

Did anybody ever see something like this? Does eventually somebody know if it's possible to force the autocompleter to finish the started requests instead of aborting them? Any other ideas?

Thanks a lot, any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally solved the issue by putting the call into a try-catch block and ignore the error if fired in IE7.

It's probably not the perfect way to do it, but the benefits of aborting the request remain valid for the rest of the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch you're just using the string value to the `source` option and supplying it a URL. You are correct about the widget aborting AJAX requests if one is in progress. [Check out this snippet](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L302) from the widget's source code:

```
url = this.options.source;
this.source = function(request, response) {
    if (self.xhr) {
        self.xhr.abort(); // <-- Problematic line.
    }
    self.xhr = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: request,
        dataType: "json",
        autocompleteRequest: ++requestIndex,
        success: function(data, status) {
            if (this.autocompleteRequest === requestIndex) {
                response(data);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            if (this.autocompleteRequest === requestIndex) {
                response([]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If you are passing a string to the `source` parameter, you can easily replace that with a function that does the AJAX call manually (and that you don't abort the request in):

```
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "your_url",
        data: request.term,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, status) {
            response(data);
        }
    });
}
```

*(Untested, but should get you headed in the right direction)*